MongoDB best practices for many sensors (+50k) but slow updates (every 12hrs)
I am trying to get some advice on how to appropriately structure my MongoDB Database. I am on Mongo Atlas M10 and my data structure looks like this:
{
    sensorId: "12345",
    epoch: Date,
    datum_1: "string",
    datum_2: "string",
    ...
}

Let's say I have 50,000+ and growing number of sensors, but the update rate is only twice a day. I've looked at a lot of posts that focus on IoT but they mostly focus on relatively small amount of sensors and high-rate of data entries. (or other examples like finance/stocks; high-rate, low count of companies)
In the end, I want to show in a GUI, historical data of a particular sensor.
One thing to add is that I really do not want to have duplicate entries that overlap in sensorId and epoch.

Any advice would be greatly appreciated! To me, with the amount of sensors and "slow" update cadence, almost seems like I should not bucket them and just have a flat structure... I don't even know what to really search for at this point.
This is what I know so far:

Timeseries MongoDB database is out of the question because it I can only $match entries by metadata, not the timestamp itself (.e.g., find if an entry with same ID + timestamp exists; if not, add); it seems like a moot point anyway because I cannot use a Timeseries DB to find existing entries and insert them (upsert).

I should not have a "sensor" based document appending new data-points in an array because a "document" has a 16MB limit on MongoDB; and I believe there is an array length limit as well. I should store / bucket each data-point as a document.



2A. I also saw some posts dividing out data by having a "Collection" per sensor, but that doesn't seem scalable...


A lot of the article regarding IoT discuss few sensors & high-output. Thus, they bucket them via time increments (seconds, minutes, hours). However, my use case is almost the opposite where I have a lot of sensors outputting data pretty slowly (relatively speaking).


A few insights that may help.
One of the advantages of using a time-series collection vs. a regular collection in MongoDB is to achieve better compression of data and therefore lower disk usage. To achieve this, you want to pack as many measurements into a bucket as possible.

Each document should logically represent one measurement. Do not pack multiple into one document, this will negatively impact disk usage/compression.
You should not be bucketing yourself, leave that to the database. Choose the correct granularity. In your case, the longest one, hours, would be best. Perhaps even customizing via some server parameters.
Use metaField (docs), not separate collections, to slice sensors into separate buckets.
Each new major version of MongoDB has significant improvements for time-series, so using the latest version possible will yield the most benefit.

As for $match not being allowed on time-series... do you have an example or a citation? From the docs here and here(examples contained), I don't see evidence of limitations you speak of in this area.
These docs pages should help:

https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/core/timeseries/timeseries-best-practices/
https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/core/timeseries-collections/

